# Stitched applications

Tags: single-word-requests, archaicisms

In old cartoons there is often _____ hanging on the wall, reading "home, sweet home" and the like, often framed. As far as this question is concerned, this stuff is sewen, stiched, knitted, you tell me. What is this thing called?

I'd call this *Stickerei* in German and the dictionary offers "(archaic) stitchery", but this applies broadly to any stitched decoration, e.g. on cushions, jackets. It also offers *embroydery, fancy-work* for synonyms. *Tapestry* seems to come close, but rather describes a hanging rug (a *flying carpet*, isn't it). Is any of these preferentially used to describe the stitched plaques, is *plaque* a good fit, or are there specialized dialectal terms? And what's up with that anyway, what's the tradition called?

<sub>Reason I'm asking is this *Ger* "Applikation" describes embroydery, funny enough, and through the correspondance p ~ f may relate to *Flicken* "plug, patch". *patch-work* has gained a different sense, though. Ger *Stepp-* could relate to *tape-*, but I am not sure.</sub>

Comment: An embroidered sampler demonstrating needlework. Good ones are collectible. Here’s an article about them. https://www.metmuseum.org/toah/hd/need/hd_need.htm

Comment: Strictly speaking, a sampler is a panel showing _samples_ of different stitches, while mottoes such as 'Home, sweet home' are often worked just in cross-stitch. However, a search on 'framed cross stitch motto' brings up photos of items which their owners describe as samplers.

Comment: Needlework, needlepoint, cross-stitch, stitchery, embroidery, sampler, wall hanging, tapestry.

Comment: Plaque is absolutely wrong. It is seldom if ever used for anything worked with threads. Plaques are usually cast in metal (or plastic).

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Not necessarily. A sampler is (Chambers) “a test-piece of embroidery, commonly including an alphabet with figures, names etc.” If you think that is what the poster means, please make it into an answer, no a comment.

Comment: I hate to presume to correct your German, but unless you are a textile expert, I would dispute that Applikation means embroidery. It means *appliqué*, which is a specialised technique in which separately worked pieces of embroidery or lace are sewn (note spelling) onto net, as @HotLicks mentions in has comment on that answer.

Comment: @David, few things are absolute. I do care very little for what it means, but what it has meant. As far as my German is in question, it stands to reason that an Applikation is *applied* like the patch of a punk-rock band to jackets (or nets if you will), but that is a loan word, not German. If it were Germanic, it would be neat to equate *ad-* (ad-plic-) with Ger *Eid* (basically a *motto*, a sworn statement). As for *sample*, I'd suppose *Saum*, *exemplar*, *ample* (viz *lantern*) and compare *plique* to *pflücken* "pick, harvest" because I've sampled a lot of music, ripping the fruit out.

Comment: Also compare *sample* to Ger *Fetzen, fetzen* "shred, to rip; also rags", possibly related to an old word for *Saum, Tasche*, viz theories on the origin of *Votze* "cunt". An *Abriss*, from *reißen* (archaic "to write, stitch", homonym with "to rip, pull"), is an overview, homonym with a *rip-off, ripped-off piece* by composition, and with *deconstruction, tear down* by idiomatics.

Comment: Which dictionary gave you *(archaic) stitchery*?

Comment: @aparente001 https://dict.cc/?s=Stickerei

Comment: @vectory - Thanks for the link.  Why did you skip over the first entry, *embroidery*, and give us the fourth entry, *stitchery (archaic)*?  The format of that dictionary is a bit unusual, but for most purposes, one can ignore anything with "archaic" in parentheses.  (Given that you didn't specify a time period, we can assume you are seeking a modern term.)

Comment: @aparente001 I had tagged the question "archaism" on purpose, before a zealous admin edited that. No doubt most readers would have missed it anyway. Also, I did note *embroidery*, didn't I? I just wasn't sure whether it is most appropriate to use figuratively denoting an embroidered piece. Hence I had tagged this also "word-choice". However, the "word-request" crowd did a better job of it, I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: cross stitch sampler]

**Sampler** or **cross-stitch sampler**

(Cross stitch is a particular type of embroidery.)

Here is a short article that gives you some terminology and will also help you understand how embroidery fit into women's life course in the 18th century: *[American Needlework in the Eighteenth Century](https://www.metmuseum.org/toah/hd/need/hd_need.htm)*

A how-to book with images and some historical information, *[Cross Stitch Antique Samplers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0715326600)*, states:

> The term 'sampler' comes from the Latin *exemplum*, meaning an example to be followed, a pattern or model.

(Wall hangings would most often hang from a dowel rod.  Which is not what you saw in the animated films.)

Here is an example of a "Home Sweet Home" sampler from an old animated film, which I found with a Google Images search.

[image: Puss Gets the Boot 1940]

Now, your sample sentence:

> In old cartoons there is often a **sampler** hanging on the wall, reading "home, sweet home" and the like, often framed.

Comment: a) I'm not sure why this is called a sampler, or since when; Under the assumption of it being an example I would try to avoid using it for purposefully mass produced pieces, but given the original sense seen at the root, that means *cut-out, excerpt* I'm quite willing to suppose an older sense at home with the snyder (difficult to explain, cp. *snip, snippet*; related question concerning *tatters* already opened) b) I see no reason why a sampler has to be cross-stitched other than the rather recent trend culminating in 18th century schools-wide compulsory cross-stitching classes which are ...

Comment: ... surely the biggest influence for our current perception of the matter. After all, I see no reason why a motto sampler made from cut-out letters, that is appliques, should not count. Thus I don't know which to up-vote.

Comment: @vectory - the original question asked about the framed "Home Sweet Home" on the wall in old cartoons.  It is a simplification of something that was quite common in a earlier period in the United State.  It is a cultural trope.  There are multiple ways of describing it, however, the most apt and common would be "cross stitch sampler."  The embroidered homily see in the old cartoons *could* have been made with appliqué techniques, *but it wasn't*.  It was made with cross stitch.  Note that the actual historical samplers might have had some other embroidery stitches, such as the French knot....

Comment: ... (remember, the trope in the cartoons was *simplified*) -- but they were unlikely to have been done with appliqué techniques.  If you want to know when and where cross stitch was used vs. appliqué, within the US, you need to ask a separate question; such a question would be a good fit for Arts and Crafts.

Comment: Now, about "archaic."  It's not enough to *tag* a question *archaic*.  If you want to know something about the usage of a word in a particular century or period, *you have to say this explicitly in the question*. // What I don't understand is why, when you looked in the dictionary, you zeroed in on the archaic definition, instead of sticking with the first entry. // That user-developed dictionary you consulted is interesting, but not standard, by the way.  It's fine to consult it, but before posting at ELU, I recommend that you check at least one of the standard dictionaries.

Comment: I added an image taken from a 1940 film. You can see that the animators weren't imagining it as having been done with appliqué.  Also, I added a quote from the second reference with a definition of *sampler*.

Answer (score 3):

It would actually be a proverbial embroidery, however it would be referred to as an **embroidery** in UK English. But according to my dictionary that is not how the word embroidery is used in US English. Although  as I have already stated it is a proverbial embroidery I fined no actual use of this term on the Internet. But there are many for **embroidery** and wall hanging.

[Embroidery Kit Link](https://www.iheartstitchart.com/listing/475562652/embroidery-kit-home-sweet-home)

A more general term for things similar but not exclusive to an embroidery sign is **Wall Hanging**

**wall hanging noun**; a large piece of material or sewing that is hung on a wall as a decoration
​

**embroidery noun UK** (SEWING) patterns or  pictures that consist of stitches sewn directly onto cloth:

**proverbial** **adjective** (of a statement) commonly known, esp. because it is from a proverb or **saying known by many people**, or because it expresses a truth known by a particular group of people:

[All references Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proverbial?topic=fame-and-famous)

Comment: I don't think the US definition of "embroidery" is much different.

Comment: My wife is a craftswoman and speaks German. Embroidery is indeed the correct translation of Stickerei and the one given in the Collins German–English dictionary.

Comment: I'd say *a piece of embroidery* rather than *an embroidery*.

Comment: From what the dictionary says in US English you would be exactly right. I'd would probably say the sign on the wall, but there again what I say and write is usually very different. Also my speciality is not sewing (I think US refer to this as point the needle or something similar) ah found it "Needlepoint" sorry.

Comment: +1 for wall-hanging. I can't think of anything closer.

Comment: @brad - I think *needlepoint* is a specific technique.  I'd guess the word you were looking for was *needlework.* // Wall hangings are generally not framed.

Answer (score -1):

***Tapestry.***

From m-w.com

> Definition of tapestry 1a: a heavy handwoven reversible textile used
>   for hangings, curtains, and upholstery and characterized by
>   complicated pictorial designs b: a nonreversible imitation of tapestry
>   used chiefly for upholstery c: embroidery on canvas resembling woven
>   tapestry needlepoint tapestry

Comment: No, a framed embroidered *Home Sweet Home* wouldn't be called a tapestry.  Even the definition cited here doesn't justify the application of the term in this case.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark "Needlepoint tapestry" is given as an example.

Comment: The OP has already mention *tapestry*, that's nothing new.

Comment: It's certainly needlepoint, but I wouldn't call them tapestries.

Comment: Tapestry is woven, not sewn. Stickerei is related to the German verb, sticken, to embroider, which is a sewing, not a weaving technique.

Comment: @David - It is possible to start with canvas and cover the entire thing with embroidery, resulting in a *tapestry*.  That would fit the definition of *needlepoint* -- but it wouldn't fit the description in the original question.

Comment: @aparente001 — Technically no. And even Chambers refers to a fixed warp, which is not a feature of embroidery. However, I agree you may find this loose usage among the general public. Just as people might call something a sampler that wasn’t a test piece. Depends how accurate you need to be.

Comment: @David - Sorry, I'm not with you.  Who's Chambers?  What's a fixed warp? // Stickerei can be done with needlepoint, I believe, and as I said, this can result in a tapestry.  The thing about this word *Stickerei* is that it's a very broad umbrella term.  At least that is the impression I have gotten from my spouse and in-laws over the years.  // I found this helpful definition of *sampler*: *The term 'sampler' comes from the Latin exemplum, meaning an example to be followed, a pattern or model.* (For the reference, please see my answer.)

Comment: @aparente001 — Sorry for being too terse. Chambers is a standard British English dictionary. I cited it as a non-technical reference. Weaving involves a two sets of threads — longitudinal threads called the warp, and lateral threads called the weft. (Embroidery is done with a single thread threaded through a needle.) So the definition of tapestry in Chambers indicates that it applies to weaving. With my wife's help I'll add an appendix to my answer explaining the different terms (and their usage) both in English and German. Better than a conversation in comments, even if of minority interest.

Comment: @aparente001 — Apologies. I never answered this question. Just voted up Embroidery and criticised all the other answers. Difficult to anwser now, and my wife is relaxing. I'll research the topic, and ask a new question and answer it myself. However I advise you not to rely on dictionaries if you are not familiar with technical craft terms. And as for German, the man in the Frankfurt street may be unfamiliar with the precise meaning of terms that a mediaeval peasant would have understood. You need to consult books or at least the German version of Wikipedia.

Comment: @David - I understand *warp* and *weft* in the general sense, but I don't know what you meant with your "fixed warp" sentence. // Cross stitch is a specific type of embroidery. // The line between embroidery and weaving can get a tiny bit fuzzy, you know.  Consider huck embroidery (also called huck weaving or Swedish weaving). // There is an Arts & Crafts stack.  Maybe that would be an interesting stack for you.

Answer (score -2):

**appliqué**

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/applique)

> Ornamental needlework in which pieces of fabric are sewn or stuck on to a larger piece to form a picture or pattern.

*Applique Tree of Life Wall Hanging*:
[image: Applique Tree of Life Wall Hanging]
<sup>© 2019 Amish Country Quilts, Lancaster, PA USA</sup>

Comment: Now that I think of it, did the OP mean *appliqué* when saying "Stitched applications"? As much as *plaque* mentioned in the body of the question? Very Close!

Comment: But the question is about embroidered slogans hanging on a wall, not embroidered pictures.  The definition cited at the top of this answer seems clearly to rule out `appliqué` as the word OP seeks.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Let's see what the OP and others have to say.

Comment: "Applique" is a specific form of stitchery, halfway between embroidery and quilting.  Relatively small pieces of cloth are stitched to the background, to form the desired pattern (which may be a picture, or may be words).  Often small details will be added using embroidery.

Comment: Lovely picture of an appliqué quilt.  Unfortunately it's totally irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @aparentee001 It's not irrelevant to the question. Donald Duck cartoons were the outset of the question, basically from when I was young. I doubt that Donald would call it a *motto sampler*. Technical terminology often deviates from an original sense;, so, if this sense of *appliqué* exists perhaps only since medival times, I don't really care for the difference. On the one hand, *appliqué* is a nominalized pp., if I'm not mistaken, and needs a noun to go with it. On the other hand, given *patch* and *patchwork*, it seems reasonable to assume that the sewn-on pieces are appliques as well ...

Comment: ... and vice versa the final product maybe a patch itself. Patches may have cross-stitch on them as well. After all, the question highlighted "Applikation", so it can't be out of the question. I'd prefer if this answer would be extended with the additional information, maybe I will get around to it. Maintaining that the question was coherent is contingent on there being a specific term that is less polysemous than *embroidery, stitching*, and that includes both and quilt, but excludes cushions. If there isn't, the question is too-broad and too-specific at the same time. Which is it?

Comment: Over all, I don't think you can see the mode of production in the cartoons. May as well be *appliques* so it counts in my book. For all I care really, these could be wood-cut with singed-in writing. A word to the practice of displaying a motto in the house would be appreciated (but this is not necessary, and it's not history.SE). In that sense, *quilt* or rather the quilt-pattern which inherently displays clan association in celtic tradition, like a house motto, is also well applicable to the question.

Comment: @vectory - Please check the meaning of "don't care for" (it means I *don't like*, not *don't care about*). // Where did "motto sampler" come from?  No one on this page has proposed "motto sampler." // Look, you try making a quilt using patchwork techniques, and another one using appliqué techniques, and then try to convince me that they're one and the same. // No, I can't imagine anyone putting cross stitch embroider on top of appliqué.  Certainly there are quilts that use appliqué and embroider, but *not* cross stitch embroidery.  I'm not saying it can't be done, but it's not standard.

Comment: In the original French, *appliqué* was an adjective, but it's been taken into English as a garden variety noun.  It's now the name of a technique. // Final products (quilts or embroidery) are never called "patches." // It's true that your question mentioned the German word "Applikation," but if you want to ask specifically about that, I recommend that you (a) not put it in a fine print footnote, and (b) put that as the primary focus of the question.  **Remember, each thing you want to ask about should go in a separate question.** // I said "appliqué" is irrelevant.  I didn't say it was...

Comment: ... *out of the question*.  // You wrote, "maybe I will get around to it" -- which doesn't make much sense in the context.  Check your understanding of this idiom, please. // I didn't say the question was too broad or too specific.  I was criticizing the answer by @Kris, because *appliqué* is not relevant to the description given in the question. // Please, let's not bring quilts into this.  That's a whole other genre. // How do I know that the decoration the animators were depicting (in simplified form) was done with cross stitch?  Because it's a cultural trope.  Also, I have done both...

Comment: ... cross stitch and appliqué.  Appliqué is inherently unsuited to lettering. Look at how cross stitch is executed and you will see that it can render any pattern you can model with graph paper and pencil.  // A woodcut, or wood burning, would not have been done by women historically.  Whereas needlework was *de rigueur* for women in earlier times. The animators wanted to reference something standard, that everyone in their audience would understand.  They were not bringing in something from left field. //

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments.